# How to execute a script that uses folder names as variables, repeating the command for each folder?

Tags: bash, debian

I am using rclone and want to write a script that auto mounts my remotes simply by creating a folder that shares a name with said remote.

My directory is structured as `/home/user/remotes/`, containing individual folders serving as mount points, 5 total.

I want to learn how to write a script that, when ran, will reference the remotes directory, and execute a mount command for each folder.

The commands generated by the script would look like

```
rclone mount FolderName1: /home/user/remotes/FolderName1 --flags

rclone mount FolderName2: /home/user/remotes/FolderName2 --flags
```

Optimally, the script will automatically generate the above commands for every folder, so that all I have to do in the future is create the folder serving as a mount point (I intend to have the script run as a cron job, so it would scan the remotes directory at regular intervals).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to just put the commands you already using in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rclone mount remote:path/to/files_1 /path/to/local/mount_1
rclone mount remote:path/to/files_2 /path/to/local/mount_2
rclone mount remote:path/to/files_3 /path/to/local/mount_3
```

The automatic way is a little trickier

```
#!/bin/sh

# get a list of directory names
dirs=$(rclone lsf --dirs-only remote:path/to/dirs)

# assuming you do not have a directory with a space in a name
for dir in $dirs
do
   # ensure you have a mount point
   mkdir -p /path/to/local/$dir

   # and mount it
   rclone mount remote:path/to/$dir /path/to/local/$dir
done
```